# Updating table with many rows

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_ids_mapping` (
 `current_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `new_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 UNIQUE KEY `current_user_id` (`current_user_id`),
 KEY `new_user_id` (`new_user_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB 

CREATE TABLE `remote_users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    ..
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The first table holds old `user_id` values and new ones, what I want to do is to update the second table `remote_users` user_id with the new values.

I do it by running 2 queries:

```
SELECT id FROM remote_users
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT {limit}
OFFSET {offset}
```

And when having the next ids, I run:

```
UPDATE remote_users r
JOIN users_ids_mapping m ON m.current_user_id = r.user_id
SET r.user_id = m.new_user_id
WHERE r.id IN({string.Join(",", ids)})
```

`users_ids_mapping` can reach to around 100k rows.

I am using batches of `10k rows`. This worked for costumers with `remote_users` table of 10-100m rows, but now i ran it on a costumer with around 200m+ rows and its simply takes too much time.

I can see that in the beginning its pretty fast:

`running batch number:1 with offset:10000 found:10000 rows, took:76ms`

But when the offset is high it takes almost 3 mins to update 10k rows:

`running batch number:13678 with offset:136780000 found:10000 rows, took:185949ms`

Any suggestions on how I can speed up the process?

Comment: Why not simple `UPDATE users_ids_mapping m, 
       remote_users u
SET u.user_id = m.new_user_id
WHERE u.user_id = m.current_user_id`? What reason makes you to use "batches"?

Comment: too many rows for one update, also I need a sense of progress to show to the customer

Comment: Have you tried using a temporary table with a JOIN, instead of `IN`?

Answer (score 0):

> too many rows for one update

If so use simple

```sql
UPDATE users_ids_mapping m, 
       remote_users u
SET u.user_id = m.new_user_id
WHERE u.user_id = m.current_user_id
LIMIT 1000
```

Replace 1000 with a chunk size which is safe for you - both for resource consumption and for progress displaying.

Repeat until "Affected rows = 0". Set approximate upper limit of the progressbar with = 1 + (count of records in `users_ids_mapping`) / (chunk size)

---

### UPDATE

> For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

```sql
UPDATE remote_users u
SET user_id = ( SELECT new_user_id
                  FROM users_ids_mapping
                  WHERE u.user_id = current_user_id )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT new_user_id
               FROM users_ids_mapping
               WHERE u.user_id = current_user_id )
LIMIT ??? ;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f80c8a00c841de9e9a13bd89883e8b0c)

Comment: not working, `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html` : `For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.`

Comment: this is not good, you are assuming new_user_id is unique, but new_user_id can be the old_user_id of another row.

Comment: @omri You're right, and I understand this. Globally the solution must include starting query with CTE over `users_ids_mapping` which will clear such chain replaces with one final replace by joining the whole chain into one record. And check that multiple records with the same `current_user_id` not exists. And check that there is no record in `users_ids_mapping` which will cause duplicates by `user_id` in `remote_users`...

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a `UPDATEing` a huge number of rows will take an unreasonable length of time.  (Ditto for `DELETE`.)

If most of the table is being changed, then *probably* the fastest way is to create a new table with the 'correct' values.  Then use `RENAME TABLE` to swap the new table into place.

Here are several tips on doing 'big' deletes or updates:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks